# How to add a drop down menu to a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

This may be a question asked before. I searched a lot before posting here, but couldn't figure out any acceptable one.

Can some one show me a way how to do this. I simply need to get a drop down menu when i click on the cell so that I'll have to select a value from that (as a way to restrict the user selection).

If some one can help with this I believe it will help a lot of people out there. There are a lots of questions similar to this but no any clear answer. Please answer with a bit more details. An example would be much appreciated..

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- use [DefaultCellEditor with DefaultTableModel for JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) in the event that all the `JComboBoxes` will have identical values in the concrete TableColumn
- if will have not identical values, then to use `DefaultCellEditor` for `JComboBoxes` with custom `AbstractTableModel`

Comment: Thanks it works! much better. This is is a correct implementation i guess, isn't it... :p

Comment: @SumuduLanskara it's the preferred implementation