# how to get drop down list using jquery?

Tags: java, json, jsp, gson, jquery-jtable

I want to show the drop down list using jtable option feature.
I tried all my best but I didn't able to figure out where I'm getting stuck.
And one more thing i want to tell u that I am using **GSON** library instead of **JSON**  library. Please any one can help me. Please try to resolve it using GSON libray

(**See the last line of jsp code from where I'm trying to get the list** )

All the solution given in this forum are based on java code but I want through jtable which get json value from java code.

***JSP COde:***

```
$('#glmetagrid').jtable({
                        title : 'MetaData Rules',
                        paging : true, //Enable paging
                        pageSize : 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
                        sorting : false, //Enable sorting
                        jqueryuiTheme : true,
                        openChildAsAccordion : true,
                        actions : {
                            listAction : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/globallink/ajax/grid?type=metadataLoad',
                            createAction : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/globallink/ajax/crud?config=metadataConfig',
                            deleteAction : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/globallink/ajax/grid?type=metadataDelete'                         
                        },
                            targetLocale : {
                                title : 'Target Locale',
                                width : '20%',
                                create : true,
                                edit : false,
                                options: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/globallink/ajax/grid?type=targetLocaleList'
                            },
```

**JAVA CODE:**

```
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("targetLocaleList")) {

                Map<String, String> targetLoacleList =getTargetLocaleList();

                String strMap = new Gson().toJson(targetLoacleList);
                Logger.debug("TargetList"+strMap);
                response.getWriter().write(strMap);
}

public Map<String, String> getTargetLocaleList() {

        try {
            GloballinkConfigService configService= new GloballinkConfigService();

            Map<String,String> targetMap = configService.getTargetLocales();

            return targetMap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e);
            Logger.error(GL_ERROR_PREFIX, e.getMessage());
            return new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a drop down menu to a JTable cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684903/how-to-add-a-drop-down-menu-to-a-jtable-cell)

Comment: @Ceiling Gecko, but this example is based on java code but I want through Jtable. Would u see the question again?